# Avoid a dynamically injected deferred script to be injected two times?

Tags: javascript

You are developing two JavaScript widget, say `first_widget.js` and `second_widget.js`, both relaying on `shared_library.js`, which is creating the global `window.MyLibrary`.

Normally, you would use the two widgets like this, where **`shared_library.js` is imported only once**:

```html
<!-- The first widget -->
<div id="first_widget_root"></div>
<script src="https://example.com/first_widget.js"></script>

<!-- The second widget -->
<div id="second_widget_root"></div>
<script src="https://example.com/second_widget.js"></script>

<!-- The shared library -->
<script src="https://example.com/shared_library.js"></script>
```

Then you decide to simplify things, **embedding the loading of `shared_library.js` into each script**:

```js
// first_widget and second_widget skeleton
var loadCallback = function () {
    // Use window.MyLibrary
};

(function(document, tag) {
    var script = document.createElement(tag),
        el = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    script.src = 'https://example.com/shared_library.js';
    script.defer = true; // Execute after HTML parsing ends
    script.onload = function () {
        loadCallback();
    };

    el.parentNode.insertBefore(script, el);
}(document, 'script'));
```

Nice, now one can use the widget more easily:

```html
<!-- The first widget -->
<div id="first_widget_root"></div>
<script src="https://example.com/first_widget.js"></script>
```

When using both widgets, **the problem is `shared_library.js` imported twice**: how would you check and inject the script only one?

I was thinking about adding a check for `window.MyLibrary` but I think isn't reliable: `shared_library.js` is imported twice depending on the loading speed anyways.

Comment: I take it *modules* isn't an option? why not check for the existence of a script with `'https://example.com/shared_library.js'` as the `src`?

Comment: That's a good idea! What do you mean for modules? U mean <script type="module">?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean by modules

Comment: How would i solve the double import with modules? Sorry for asking, can't understand how. You could write a quick answer instead.

Comment: no, since I have not enough info about the .js files to write a meaningful answer

Answer (score 1):

In your case:

```
   if(! document.querySelector('script[src*=shared_library]'){
    // insert
   }
```

That is a common practice to check whether a child of dom is  containing smth in its attribute (need of some browser support probably to write such comfortable code) and, if not existent, it's to be quietly inserted there into the document.

Alongside with real site examples, SO is often talking about this topic of finding a script to whether it's to be inserted or the script is already loading like in this, for example:

```
 //given url argument, in a call, e.g url='http://example.com/shared_library.js'
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var i = scripts.length; i--;) {
    if (scripts[i].src == url) return true;
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Seems a nice solution to me. You say it's a common practice? Do you have some examples?